# Excel Formula to return =MIN() value heading

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Created an excel field that does a lookup across a row and returns the min value

[image: Example data]

What id like to do in the next cell along is add a formula that tells me what Heading is the lowest as well. So it would say Value 4.

Haven't been able to work out a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `INDEX`
Either in the next cell `=INDEX(B5:G6,1,MATCH(H6,B6:G6,0))`

or nest it

`INDEX(B5:G6,1,MATCH(MIN(B6:G6),B6:G6,0))`

Answer (score 0):

please try like this
`=INDEX($B$1:$G$6,1,MATCH(H6,B6:D6,0))`
paste this formula in `I6 cell`
here i assumed that headers are in firs row `B1:G1`